# How to create an animated line chart from dataframe's columns?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, matplotlib-animation

I have this dataframe called `vars` and I'm trying to plot an animated line chart, with each column being one line (except the date column that would be the x axis).

```
 data      var_brl  var_ars var_bob var_clp var_cop var_mxn var_pen var_pyg var_uyu
0   01/01/2020  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
1   02/01/2020  0.17    -0.10   0.14    -0.36   -1.01   -0.49   -0.41   0.41    0.16
2   03/01/2020  1.19    -0.22   0.07    1.65    -1.01   -0.04   0.11    0.49    -0.38
3   04/01/2020  1.19    -0.22   0.07    1.65    -1.01   -0.04   0.11    0.49    -0.38
4   05/01/2020  1.19    -0.22   0.07    1.65    -1.01   -0.04   0.11    0.49    -0.38
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
135 15/05/2020  45.71   13.03   -0.07   10.07   18.98   26.43   3.78    1.81    18.19
136 16/05/2020  45.71   13.03   -0.07   10.07   18.98   26.43   3.78    1.81    18.19
137 17/05/2020  45.71   13.03   -0.07   10.07   18.98   26.43   3.78    1.81    18.19
138 18/05/2020  42.32   13.28   0.00    8.92    17.20   25.49   3.47    2.09    18.06
139 19/05/2020  43.20   13.43   0.00    8.88    16.69   25.08   3.46    2.10    18.06
```

This the code I'm using:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8))

plt.style.use('ggplot')

months = mdates.MonthLocator()
months_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%Y')

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(months_fmt)

limx_i = vars.iloc[0, 0]
limx_f = vars.iloc[-1, 0]
limy_f = vars.iloc[:, 1:].max().max()
limy_i = vars.iloc[:, 1:].min().min()

ax.set_xlim(limx_i, limx_f + dt.timedelta(days=30))
ax.set_ylim(limy_i, limy_f)

line, = [ax.plot([], [], lw=2)]
for i in range(1, vars.shape[1]):

    def animate(i):
        line.set_data(vars['data'], vars.iloc[:, i])
        return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=140, interval=20, blit=True)

ax.tick_params(bottom=False, top=False, right=False, left=False)
ax.set_ylabel('Oscilação acumulada %')
plt.grid(False)

for key, spine in ax.spines.items():
    spine.set_visible(False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I need to iterate over the dataframe because the code must work regardless of the number of columns.

This is as far as I'm going:
[image]

It plots the image above (with no lines) and then it raises the following error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_data'`

I'm kind of inexperienced with animations so any help will be much appreciated. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

[EDIT]

I'm looking for an animation like this:

[image]

But with a line for each column. And I can't figure out how to build an animated chart like this with multiple lines.

I understand that I have to use `FuncAnimation` from `matplotlib.animation` but I'm having problems with it.

I got this char from [this Towards Data Science post](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-animated-graphs-in-python-bb619cc2dec1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to avoid using `vars` as a variable name because it is a builtin function in Python. You can loop over the columns as shown in the for loop below.The animation can be achieved by using matplotlib's interactive mode in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
# test file 
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt',sep='\s+')
def convert_date(df):
    return datetime.strptime(df['data'], '%d/%m/%Y')
df['data'] = df.apply(convert_date, axis=1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()



limx_i = df.iloc[0, 0]
limx_f = df.iloc[-1, 0]
limy_f = df.iloc[:, 1:].max().max()
limy_i = df.iloc[:, 1:].min().min()

ax.set_xlim(limx_i, limx_f)
ax.set_ylim(limy_i, limy_f)
plt.ion()   # set interactive mode
plt.show()

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    plt.cla()
    df.iloc[:i+1,:].plot(x='data', ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlim(limx_i, limx_f)
    ax.set_ylim(limy_i, limy_f)
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to help. However, it raises the following error in the `plt.show()` line: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'session'`. Do you know what that's about?

Comment: For me the code runs perfectly fine on Python 3.6.9. If you are not using a Jupyter notebook, you want to remove the line `matplotlib.use("nbagg")`. The error you get could be due to the backend invoked by using `nbagg`

Comment: Oh, ok. It worked without the `matplotlib.use("nbagg")`. Thank you! However, this animation works by plotting one line at a time. What I'm looking for is an animation the shows all the lines being drawn at the same time. Can you help with that?

Comment: If you found this or any other solution helpful and it resolved your problem, you want to check the green mark. This will help keep the focus on unanswered questions.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for helping, but this is not quite what I'm looking for. See edits in the post. Appreciate your efforts to help.

Comment: This does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: It is a little different. It kind looks like it is "going backwards". In the first frame, for example, the lines are crossing the chart, and not being drawing along the chart as image I posted.

Comment: To do that you want to set the axis limits within the loop. This will fix the axis limits. As you can see in the code above, I have commented out the axis limits. After clearing the axis `plt.cla()`, simply put in `ax.set_xlim(beginning, end)`

Comment: Oh, ok! Now it looks good! Thank you! Can I ask a couple o questions? I don't have `plt.legend` set but the legend is still there and I don't want it. How do I take it off? And if want to use `ax.text` should do it inside the `for`? Thank you again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214745/discussion-between-sameeresque-and-otavio-simoes-silveira).